# I'm having trouble with the python struct.pack() function for packing data into a byte sequence

Tags: python, modbus

```
In [2]: struct.pack(">BHH", 6, 8202, 4).hex()
Out[2]: '06200a0004'
```

It should output：'0620**10**0004'.
It should be a modbus instruction, which will cause the crc validation to fail, how can I fix it

Comment: `8202` is `32*256 + 10`. So its bytes are (in denary) `32` and `10`. In hex that's `20` and `0a`. Can you say why you're expecting `0620100004` ?

Comment: Because it is a modbus instruction, if it shows 0a, it is invalid to input the device. And it's not the same as the CRC verification code that shows 10.
That's right：01 06 20 10 00 04 82 0C
mistake：01 06 20 0a 00 04 a3 cb

Comment: @djc you specify `8202` in the arguments to `pack` so the output will be `200a` (`8202` decimal = `200A` hex); if you want `2010` then use `struct.pack(">BHH", 6, 8208, 4)` (`8208` decimal = `2010` hex). The CRC is not relevant at this stage (that would be calculated later).

Comment: Or indeed you can do `struct.pack(">BHH", 0x06, 0x2010, 0x04)` - Python lets you enter literal hex numbers by preceding them with `0x`.